# Opengl es 1.1/Android -- How to make a smooth gradient for a triangle filled using a colorPointer

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I've got some triangles rendered using triangle strips and colored using a colorPointer (two vertices white, one vertex black). The gradient works, but when the triangle size increases, the gradient appears choppy.

I could switch to _TRIANGLES or _TRIANGLE_FAN, that really isn't the issue so much as how to make a smooth gradient without resorting to increasing the triangle count. Any suggestions?

Comment: What I've found that makes a noticeable difference is creating a/the triangle with vertices further apart, then scaling it down to fit the desired size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the default color depth ?

When you create your GLSurfaceView, call something like
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0); (last 2 zeros for no stencil and depth buffer).
You have to do it before you set a Renderer.

See [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html)

Comment: Seems like that would affect performance since it is applied to all rendering. I'm just trying to get one object type to look smooth. Thanks for the input.